# optimize loop logic for displaying structure

Tags: php, logic, structure, formula

I want to order 3 articles per row while every other line one article has a wide image displayed filling two spots out of three.
this is the code I came up with but it seems very complicated for something that "easy". example output at the bottom.

maybe someone knows something that can do the same but simpler.

Thanks!

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $x = 0;
    $first = false;
    $three = false;
    $five = true;
    foreach( range( 0, 27 ) as $k ) {
        if( $x != 0 && $x % 3 == 0 ) {
            echo "\n";
        }
        $x++;
        $i++;
        if( !$first && $i == 5 ) {
            $i = 0;
            $x++;
            $first = true;
            echo '[__]';
        }
        elseif( $first && !$three && $i == 4 ) {
            $i = 0;
            $x++;
            $three = true;
            $five = false;
            echo '[__]';
        }
        elseif( $first && !$five && $i == 6 ) {
            $i = 0;
            $x++;
            $three = false;
            $five = true;
            echo '[__]';
        }
        else echo '[]';
    }
?>
```

output:

```
[][][]
[][__]
[][][]
[__][]
[][][]
[][__]
[][][]
[__][]
[][][]
[][__]
[][][]
```

Comment: What is 27, $first, $three, $five?

Comment: variables to switch between 3 and 5 items between long. 27 is just a number for the range. you could create 500 instead of 27, check the output example - imagine each box is a image, small image vs. wide image

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you looking for all possible combinations or what? If you are given a list of articles with those images - I can't see an original array in your code.

Comment: he need to get that shape with simpler way

Comment: If he needs to print this shape, he can call six echos in a loop.

Comment: axalix it's for a website, those are images. what if there are 5000 items in that array, 3 per line, every second line has one item taking 2 spots.

Comment: `foreach ([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0] as $size) { echo $size ? '[' . str_repeat('_', $size - 1) . ']' : "\n"; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have 27 articles

```
$articles = 27 / 3;
```

i have this way i hope it work with you  **UPDATED**

```
<?php
    $x = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $articles; $i++) {
        for($j = 0;$j < 3;$j++) {
            if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                if ($x && $j % 2 == 0) {
                    echo '[ ] ';
                } else {
                    echo '[ _ ] ';
                    $x = !$x;
                    $j++;
                }
            } else {
                echo '[ ]';
            }
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }
?>
```

and this is my result

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

just change the first loop to be

```
$i=1
```

so it can't mod 2 so you got the first three, then change the

```
if($x && $i % 2 == 0)
```

to be true like this

```
if(!$x && $i % 2 == 0)
```

**THE EXAMPLE**

```
<?php
    $count = 7;
    $articles = ceil($count / 3);
    $articles = $articles + ceil(ceil($articles/2) / 3);
    $x = false;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $articles; $i++) {
        if ($count == 0) break;
        for($j = 0;$j < 3;$j++) {
            if ($count == 0) break;
            if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                if (!$x && $j % 2 == 0) {
                    echo '[ ] ';
                } else {
                    echo '[ _ ] ';
                    $x = !$x;
                    $j++;
                }
            } else {
                echo '[ ]';
            }
            $count--;
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }
?>
```

image result

[image]

Comment: now here is the trick, the first line needs to be 3, then one, then wide like my example - that's the shitty part. it's 4, then first 3 and then rotating 5 and 3 :D - but yes your solution is much nicer already

Comment: @Tobias , ohh sorry bout that, no problem please see my update

Comment: awesome! very very good job compressing this :D thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone needs it as twig implementation:

```
{% import _self as macros %}
{% set rows = ( items|length / 3 ) %}
{% set x = false %}
{% set y = 0 %}

{% for i in 1..rows+2 %}
    {% set skip = false %}
    {% for j in 0..2 %}
        {% if skip %}
            {% set skip = false %}
        {% else %}
            {% if i is divisible by(2) %}
                {% if x == false and j is divisible by(2) %}
                    {{ macros.item( items[y] ) }}
                    {% set y = y + 1 %}
                {% else %}
                    {{ macros.item( items[y], true ) }}
                    {% set y = y + 1 %}
                    {% set skip = true %}
                    {% if x == false  %}
                        {% set x = true %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% set x = false %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {{ macros.item( items[y] ) }}
                {% set y = y + 1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

macro = bootstrap block element, if set to true col width goes from 4 to 8 to cover two spots - had to implement a skip variable because in twig you can't edit the loop index - added additional independent counter to go through the article array, rows+2 based on / 3 and total of 33 articles per page.